# How to install Windows 8 onto my laptop

Tags: windows-8.1, installation

I recently had to purchase a hard drive for my laptop. I bought a solid state drive and now I need to get an isolated for windows the problem is I don't have good internet so I can't download the file. So I want to rip a copy from my tablet. Which files and/or programs do I need to install Windows on the new hardware
Edit: The laptop is a 32bit system

Comment: Is there a reason using a Windows 8.1 ISO isn’t an option?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This isn't an option. You need to have a windows installer (or any OS installer for that matter) to install an OS onto a clean drive. Simply copying the files wont work.

That said, it is possible that you could clone the entire hard drive from the tablet to the SSD. But even in that instance, the OS is different from the laptop version and there may be compatibility issues within the hardware. The best thing you can do is go buy it from the store, or wait for the download to complete. Even if you were to torrent the installer, you'd need to wait for the transfer to complete.

Good Luck!

Comment: The problem is I don't have any Internet at all and even if I did I don't have the product key

Comment: I would recommend starbucks or the library for some free wifi. The key for a standard home edition isnt too awful in price. But you must have some internet if youre on stack overflow 